# How to correctly get command output while using Command Applet in MATE?

Tags: bash, scripts, 20.04, mate, mate-panel

I have added [Command Applet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dt4im.png) to the MATE Panel.

I planed to use a command with some scripting inside to check server availability - something like

```
wget --quiet https://someserver -O - | grep -s somedata > /dev/null && echo "S OK" || echo "S FAIL!"
```

or

```
curl -s https://someserver | grep -s somedata > /dev/null && echo "S OK" || echo "S FAIL!"
```

I have added this command to [Preferences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2dHT.png).

In terminal it works as expected, but Command Applet shows only `#` inside:

[image: Command output]

I tried to move the long command to script file, but got the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is really simple, one have to save the command into script file like `/home/user/bin/script.sh`, make it executable by `chmod +x /home/user/bin/script.sh` and then enter this path `/home/user/bin/script.sh` in Command field of Command Applet.